# Windows Phone 8 X509Certificate with private key data format

Tags: windows-phone-8, x509certificate, private-key

I'd like to import a certificate and private key into a Windows Phone 8 app. The X509Certificate [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms148393(v=vs.105).aspx) says "...does not accept input data formatted in the PKCS #12 format...". Can anyone tell me what data format it does accept? Barring that, can you tell me the easiest way to get a certificate and private key into a Windows Phone 8 app via a resource?

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like a typo on the page. `rawData` parameter definitely should support PKCS#12.

Comment: I tried PKCS#12 and it didn't work, neither reading it from a pfx resource file nor a binary resource file. I also tried a binary resource file that held a the output from X509Certificate.Export() using the X509ContentType.SerializedCert which supports private keys; that failed too. In all cases the exception message is "Cannot find the requested object." I was able to deserialize them successfully on the desktop.